# Does tf.control_dependencies really work in my small program?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I wrote a samll program to test how `tf.control_dependencies` work, result seems to be confused to me however. My test code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0.0)
y = None
for i in range(5):
    assign_op = tf.assign(x, i)
    with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
        y = tf.identity(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x))
    print(sess.run(y))
```

when i run the program, value of `x` and `y` are `0.0` and `4.0` respectively. Since value of `y` gets the right answer, `assign_op` in `tf.control_dependencies` works in this example. Then as the op works correctly, why does't the value of `x` equal to `4.0`?
Please correct me if I have any misunderstanding of how `tf.control_dependencies` really work.

Answer (score 2):

Because, until you run the `y` no assignment has been made.

You have to think about your program as a computational graph. By setting the dependency you are telling to Tensorflow "when you evaluate y, make sure the assignment has been already performed".

But you are telling anything about what to do when running `x` the first time.

Try running `sess.run(x)` after the `sess.run(y)` and you will see your expected result.

[image: Simplified version of the graph]

In the image,you have to think to the horizontal line as something like a "join" control operation: wait for all the "below" operation before evaluating the node".

Answer (score 2):

This is because you haven't executed the `assign_op` operation. This is what you want:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(assign_op)
    print(sess.run(x))
    print(sess.run(y))
# 4.0
# 4.0
```

But you're calling `sess.run(x)` first and it evaluates it to the initial value `0.0`. If you would call `sess.run(y)` first, it would first execute the assignment of `x` and then, evaluate `y` to the same value as `x`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(y))
    print(sess.run(x))
# 4.0
# 4.0
```

So you need to call `sess.run(y)` first.